# remove the all documents older then 7 days in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am able to remove the all documents older then 7 days from the mongo shell with the below query..

```
db.test.remove({"trans_date" : {"$lt": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7))}});
```

-->output when execute the query

```
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 9 })
```

But with the same query in the shell script no records are deleting, below is the code of shell script..

```
mongo --host=192.168.0.15 --port=25980 --username=myuser --password 'myuser$1010' --authenticationDatabase=admin << EOF
use db1;
db.test.remove({"trans_date" : {"$lt": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7))}});
exit;
EOF
```

-->output when execute the shell script

```
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })
```

Please suggest to remove the same with the shell script, so that I can schedule the shell script in the cronjob to

Comment: Have you checked out [MongoDB TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)?

Comment: Yes I checked and TTL Index is working fine. But with TTL Index I am not able to store the deleted documents in the file.  First I am exporting the documents older then 7 days then want to remove these.